# Installing Powerpivot for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to install power pivot for SharePoint 2013, but not sure where to install the SQL Analysis service.

Do I need to run the SQL setup on SharePoint application server or SQL server to install the analysis.

When I run sppowerpivot.msi tool it is mentioned i need to install on the servers in the farm and configuration tool on any two servers. how do I deselect only the configuration tool?

Answer (score 1):

PowerPivot IS an Analysis Services instance (it runs in-memory using the Vertipaq database engine) ... it actually creates a new SSAS SQL Instance when you install the PowerPivot component from the SQL Server installer.

The steps I typically follow are:

1. Install SharePoint on the server and Join it to the Farm with minimal services
2. Run SQL Installer and install PowerPivot and SSRS components
3. Add and Deploy the PowerPivot WSP (if you haven't already)
4. Create Service Apps / Start services from "services on server"

From there you should be good to go